# Custom Field - Do Not Show if Value is Empty?

Tags: custom-field

This is the code I've added to a single.php file and I need to NOT display the Article Reference echo line, if the custom field value is empty.

I am using Genesis, if that matters.

How should this be written?  Also, is there a better way to write this code?

Thanks,
Louise

```
function custom_do_grid_loop() {
// Intro Text (from page content)
echo '<div class="page hentry entry">';
echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<div class="import-image">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
} 
echo '<div class="entry-content"><p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
echo '<div class="field_name"><strong>Article Reference:</strong> ' . genesis_get_custom_field( 'article_reference' ) .'</div>';

echo '</div><!-- end .entry-content -->';
echo '</div><!-- end .page .hentry .entry -->';
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm learning so much from these examples.  What if I want to check to see if the $meta value is a specific number?  For example, if the value is 20.

Comment: If any answer helped you or fixed your problem you should consider it as best answer. It would also be better if you commented on my answer so i get notified. See my edited answer well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a little check to your code

```
    function custom_do_grid_loop() {
    // Intro Text (from page content)
    echo '<div class="page hentry entry">';
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title() .'</h1>';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo '<div class="import-image">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
    } 
    echo '<div class="entry-content"><p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
    //Add this condition to your code
    $meta = genesis_get_custom_field( 'article_reference' );
    //Remove white space from both sides,
    if( !empty(trim($meta)) ){
        echo '<div class="field_name"><strong>Article Reference:</strong> ' . genesis_get_custom_field( 'article_reference' ) .'</div>';
    }
    echo '</div><!-- end .entry-content -->';
    echo '</div><!-- end .page .hentry .entry -->';
    }
```

If its not empty show it, otherwise don't.

**Edited:**

You can do something like this for further conditions

```
    if($meta == 20)
    {
        echo 'do 20';
    }
    elseif ($meta == 21)
    {
        echo 'do 21';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'If all condition fails this will be echo';
    }
```

Comment: I've seen people use this before as well: `if($meta != '')`

Comment: There are many ways for checking the empty values `isset($var)` `$var == ""` `empty($var)` `if($var)`.
But `empty` and `$var == ""` don't check for spaces from either side. See my answer

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get my code to work with your examples.  I'd like to vote but I've not been a member long enough.  ;)

Comment: How do I make accepted?